# What happens to multiple messages in ByteToMessageDecoder?

Tags: netty

I've got a question about `ByteToMessageDecoder`. The `decode` method has signature

```
public void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out)
```

where `out` is the output for the next handler in the pipeline. If I insert multiple messages by calling `out.add()` multiple times, what will the next handler see?

For example,

1. pipeline is `ByteToMessageDecoder -> SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String>`
2. in `ByteToMessageDecoder`'s `decode` method, I call `out.add("first")`, `out.add("second")`, `out.add("third")`

Given that `SimpleChannelInboundHandler`'s message handling method has signature `protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String message)`, what will I see for the `message` parameter? Will the `channelRead0` be called three times?

Comment: I suppose trying it and finding out was out of the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every message contained in the List will be forwarded to the next handler via the fireChannelRead(...) call. So your handler will be called three times in your example.